# How to refresh Angular dual-listbox after changed destination data

Tags: javascript, angular, listbox, bootstrap-duallistbox

I reordered the destination data of the dual-listbox, but the order in the destination box is not updated. Is there anyway to trigger a refresh? In html:

```
<dual-list id="one-dual-list" [sort]="keep_sorted" [source]="source" [key]="key" [display]="display" [filter]="filter"
[destination]="confirmed" height="400px" [format]="format" 
[disabled]="disabled"></dual-list>
```

On component side:

```
keep_sorted=false;
key="key";
display="group";
filter=false;
format: any = DualListComponent.DEFAULT_FORMAT;
confirmed = [
 { key: 1, group: GroupA },
 { key: 2, group: GroupB },
]
source = [
 { key: 1, group: GroupA },
 { key: 2, group: GroupB },
 { key: 3, group: GroupC },
]

onButtonClick() {
group_confirmed = [
 { key: 1, group: GroupB },
 { key: 2, group: GroupA },
]
source = [
 { key: 1, group: GroupB },
 { key: 2, group: GroupA },
 { key: 3, group: GroupC },
]
}
```

However, the display of the dual listbox is not changed. Should I let the component to emit a signal?